# Vueling hand bag rules

Tags: air-travel, luggage, electronic-items, hand-luggage, vueling

I go with Vueling, I am asking about the hand bags.

I have the standard bag (20 * 25 * 55 ) bag that I can take with me to the plain, it is 10 KG.

I am sure that one is allowed, but I want to ask if I can take my laptop in another bag with me to the plain. normally the answer is yes but my experiense with transavia was very bad, the forced me to put the laptop inside the 20 * 25 * 55 bag

so does Vueling allow me to have two hand bags, one the standard, and one the laptop ?

This is the bag
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=10&v=4_9UMEKhch0

Comment: Is that 20x25x40 the size of your bag? If so would it be an option to take a larger one that has the allowed 20x40x55. It would be slightly heavier than allowed, but chances of them checking the weight is a lot less than checking the size unless the bag would obviously be too heavy.

Comment: @ptityeti indeed my bag's size is 20 25 55, i just made a typo in the questoin, sorry

Comment: That bag (Thule Crossover 25L) is the one you would like to take as laptop bag/ small bag *in addition to* a piece of hand luggage?

Comment: @ptityeti sorry but maybe i wasn't clear, i meant that (in the Youtube video) is my bag, so do you think it is big ?

Comment: Edited my answer a little for that bag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vueling allows you to have a "small bag" in addition to your hand luggage. However, there are no hard limits on the size of this small bag. The [Conditions of Carriage](http://www.vueling.com/en/customer-services/conditions-of-carriage#luggage) state under 8.5:

> In addition, the Passenger may carry one extra item free of charge and
>   which must be significantly smaller than 55x40x20 cm, such as a small
>   briefcase, a handbag or camera.

They certainly give themselves some wiggle room in deciding what will be a small bag. It will mainly depend on the size of the laptop and the mood of the person at the gate. If it is just a small laptop, you should be OK. If it is a huge laptop bag you risk running into the same troubles as you had with Transavia.

In your question you linked to a bag that measures according to the [specifications](https://www.thule.com/en/be/backpacks/laptop-backpacks/thule-crossover-25l-_-tl_85854231350) 48x32x27cm. The depth of that bag is slightly more than what is allowed for hand luggage (55x40x20 cm) but you'll probably get away with it for the piece of hand luggage. However, I would certainly not consider those dimensions to be "significantly smaller than 55x40x20 cm". So, I would not take the risk of using it as the extra item.

Comment: Thank you, i updated the question adding the bag of the laptop, could you check please